# usb.core.find comes back none

Tags: python, usb, raspberry-pi

I am trying to get a MagTek card reader to work on my raspberry pi. I have one MagTek card reader model working just fine. It is one of their indoor models. I purchased an outdoor model (Sidewinder RS-232) and this is the one giving me the error.

This is the only bit of code that is running since it wont continue on until there is an actual device.

```
def getData():
    VENDOR_ID = 0x0801
    PRODUCT_ID = 0x0002
    DATA_SIZE = 337
    PACKET_SIZE = 0x0151
    device = usb.core.find(idVendor=VENDOR_ID, idProduct=PRODUCT_ID)
    if device is None:
        sys.exit("Could not find MagTek USB HID Swipe Reader")
```

Let me reiterate, the indoor model works just fine and from what I've seen online (http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids) uses the same Product_ID. So there is no reason that I can see why the outdoor model is not working. I'm waiting to hear back from MagTek's technical service, but I thought you guys would be faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem but it led to more.

The Side Winder RS-232 from Brush Industries has a different Vendor ID and Product ID. If you replace those variables with the correct ones (below) then your Side Winder RS-232 should be detected by your python code.

Vendor Id = 0x12b6

Product Id = 0x0092

Comment: In the future, you should use `lsusb` to inspect the devices plugged in when having trouble like this.

Comment: That's actually how I found the solution. Had the device plugged in and typed in `lsusb` saw the read out. Then unplugged the device, re-ran `lsusb` and compared that read out to the first.